# JPanel doesn't repaint well using transparent JFrame

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel, transparency

I'm trying to repaint a `JPanel` over a transparent `JFrame` but it lets the mark of the previous repaint:

[previous repaint keeps showing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LfQjd.png)

I know this is a known problem and there's a similar question already posted, but the answers only explain why it doesn't work and they don't give a solution.

Can anyone please make a change in the code or add some, so it gives the desired effect? (a cross that follows the mouse over a transparent background)

I don't want to take a picture of the desktop and draw it in the `JPanel`.

The code is the following

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

final class Transparency extends JFrame{
    private NewPanel np;

    Transparency(){
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setUndecorated(true);
        setLocation(200,200);
        setBackground(new Color(0,0,0,0));

        np = new NewPanel();
        setContentPane(np);

        pack();
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String []args){
        Transparency li = new Transparency();
    }
}

final class NewPanel extends JPanel{
    private Point p = new Point(0,0);
    private final int length = 25;

    NewPanel(){
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400,400));
        setOpaque(false);
        addMouseMotionListener(new MouseAdapter(){
            public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e){
                p = e.getPoint();
                repaint();
            }
        });
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        super.paintComponent(g);

        g.setColor(Color.GREEN);
        g.drawLine(p.x-length,p.y,p.x+length,p.y);
        g.drawLine(p.x,p.y-length,p.x,p.y+length);

        g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        g.drawRect(0,0,399,399);
    }
}
```

Comment: What OS and Java version are you using?  Can't replicate it on macOS 10.14.5 using Java 11

Comment: @MadProgrammer I used Java 8.191 on Ubuntu 16.04. I understand that Java 9 or above work only in 64-bit computers and mine is 32-bits. Maybe an old version of Java causes this effect?

Comment: “Seems” to be an issue with Linux 

Answer (score 0):

Since there is no heavyweight top level component, you will need to manage the background yourself.

Add this to your paintComponent method, right after super.paintComponent:

```
g.clearRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
```

Comment: `JFrame` extends from `Frame` which extends from `Window`, `Container` and `Component`. `JPanel` extends from `JComponent`, `Container`, `Component` - so, plenty of heavy weight lifting go on there.  While the "suggestion" might work, it doesn't solve the reason for the issue, as I can't replicate it on my system

Comment: @MadProgrammer Interesting.  I was able to replicate the problem in Linux, using Java 11.  And while every Window is technically heavyweight, I would argue that a transparent window does not provide a heavyweight background which lightweight components normally require.

Comment: Since it seems to work on Windows and MacOS, it may be a issue isolated to Linux - if that is the OPs case, then likely the solution is probably the best option at this time

Comment: @VGR unfortunately this line didn't solve the problem. And as MadProgrammer says it appears to be a Linux problem. I tested the same code on WIndows 10 with Java 8.111 and it gave a different undesired effect, but I was able to solve it just by setting a non-zero alpha value to the background color of the JFrame.